# Volley JSON Parse Foreach Loop

Tags: android, json

I've successfully parsed the JSON and shown the results in RecyclerView. But I'm totally new to Volley and Java and hence having some issues regarding parsing the objects. Here's the code I'm using:

```
url_req = new JsonArrayRequest(server_tag_url, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
        JSONObject jsonObject = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < response .length();i++){
            try {
                jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                TagUrlResultsModel tagUrlResultsModel = new TagUrlResultsModel();
                tagUrlResultsModel.setV_tags(jsonObject.getString("tag"));
                url_result.add(tagUrlResultsModel);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        results_tag(url_result);

    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

    }
});
```

Here's the JSON:

```
[
    {
        "tag": "Nice Tag"
    },
    {
        "tag": "Example"
    }
]
```

It works fine and displays all the Tags in RecyclerView. But the issue is that what if I want to get other items from the JSON file and show them in other layout items. I mean, for example, Title, Description, etc.

Here's the new JSON I want to parse:

```
{

    "title": "Awesome Title",
    "Description": "Awesome Description",
    "tags": [{
            "0": "tag1"
        },
        {
            "1": "tag2"
        },
        {
            "2": "Awesome Tag"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For title and description i would recommend adding those fields in your Model.

I recreated your object and parse it with JSON Object and then type casting to String and then again type casting it to JSON Object.

```
        try{

        // Recreating the Object
        JSONArray tags = new JSONArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            jsonObject.put(String.valueOf(i),"Tag # "+i);
            tags.put(jsonObject);
        }

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.put("title","Awesome Title");
        jsonObject.put("Description","Awesome Description");
        jsonObject.put("tags",tags);


        Log.d(TAG, "parseObject: Sample JSON "+jsonObject);

        String stringObj = String.valueOf(jsonObject);

        Log.d(TAG, "parseObject: Stringify "+ stringObj);

        JSONObject convertedObj = new JSONObject(stringObj);

        Log.d(TAG, "parseObject: Converted Obj "+convertedObj);


        String title = convertedObj.getString("title");
        String description = convertedObj.getString("Description");

        Log.d(TAG, "parseObject: Title = "+title+" -  Description = "+description);

        JSONArray parsedTagsArr = convertedObj.getJSONArray("tags");

        for (int i = 0; i < parsedTagsArr.length(); i++) {

            JSONObject jsonObject1 = parsedTagsArr.getJSONObject(i);
            Log.d(TAG, "parseObject: Tags Array "+jsonObject1);
        }



    }catch (Exception e){
        // TODO
        Log.d(TAG, "parseObject: "+e);
    }
```

Here how my logs look after executing the following code.
[image: Android Log Cat image]

Comment: In line: JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response); it says Cannot resolve constructor

Comment: Edited my answer please change your method to StringRequest or JSON request  
here is a great tutorial on volley [https://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/]

Comment: It says: java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: @Andrew i have updated the answer with more direct solution to the problem let me me know by voting up it this resolves your issues thanks.